# Can Sphinx query be tested command line w/o an index?

Tags: command-line, sphinx

If I just want to test that my query will work vs a term inside a sentence "and am selling an Iphone 3gs", is it possible to use command line to test this? This way I don't need to keep adding to and rotating an index but can simply tweak my query and the data I'd plan on storing. Mainly I am trying to tweak various query parameters like SENTENCE and PROXIMITY vs wordforms/stopwords/ignore_char and would like to be able to work fast and test different query structures vs test words/patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory can use `BuildExcerpts`, to run an arbitrary query, against a block of text (make sure use `query_mode`=true).

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-buildexcerpts

But even then not totally sure it will completely honour the query, not sure SENTENCE etc will truely work.

... but if you wanting to play with ignore_char etc, you are going to be modifying the index config file. So surely just quickly running indexer to rebuild the index, to see the results is not htat difficult.

Comment: I'm actually usings I guess SphinxQL from a mysql editor. So do you mean it might be just as easy to keep a CL window open and run -rotate each time I update the text field in the table?

Comment: basically yes. You would need to rotate the index each time change something like 'ignore_char' anyway.